# Reusing an AuthForm component without sending unnecessary info in state

Tags: reactjs, forms, state, react-hooks

I have an AuthForm component I'm using on both my /signup and /login pages, and I'm differentiating between the two with a formType prop. The signup page needs a couple extra fields, including gender and date of birth (possibly address in the future), whereas the login form can be fairly simple.

From a display standpoint this is simple, as I can show or hide those extra fields based on the value of the formType prop. Where it gets complicated is with state.

I have considered two different methods of managing state: 1) with a useFormInput() hook, and 2) with the useState hook combined with a state object (mimicking the stateful component methodology).

Option 1:

```
const useFormInput = (initialValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleChange
  };
}

const AuthForm = ({ buttonText, formType, onAuth }) => {

  const email = useFormInput(''); 
  const password = useFormInput(''); 
  ...

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onAuth(formType, {email, password, etc); 

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="email">E-mail</label>
      <input
        id="email"
        name="email"
        type="text"
        {...email}
      />
   ...
  )
};
  }
```

Option 2

```
const AuthForm = ({ buttonText, formType, onAuth }) => {

  const [state , setState] = useState({
      email : "",
      password : "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      gender: "",
      dob: ""
  })

  const handleChange = e => {
      const {name , value} = e.target;
      setState( prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          [name] : value
      }))
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
    onAuth(formType, state);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="email">E-mail</label>
      <input
        id="email"
        name="email"
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        value={state.email}
      />
   ...
  )
};
  }
```

Whichever method I go with, I can't seem to avoid having to declare each state variable. When I set state = {} in option 2, I get an error about changing uncontrolled components to controlled components. When I declare all my state variables, that means that my login form will have gender="" in state, which will then overwrite the value in my database.

**How can I either A) Avoid declaring state variables altogether, or B) make my final state only contain the fields appropriate to the context the AuthForm is being used in?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create initial state based on formType (Option 2).

```
const AuthForm = ({ buttonText, formType, onAuth }) => {

  initialStateLogin = {
      email : "",
      password : "",
  };

  initialStateSignup = {
      email : "",
      password : "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      gender: "",
      dob: ""
  };

  const [state , setState] = useState(formType === 'login' ? initialStateLogin : initialStateSignup);

  //rest of the code..

}
```